# is xStage (for any x) reserved in grails?

Tags: grails

i have a grails application which gives me unexplained errors if i use a domain MStage or NStage or TStage. these are specific terms in the doamin of the application so I don't want to change them. but for example if i change TStage to PrimaryTumourStage then all is well.

very confused

Comment: What errors are you getting? Can you include those in your question? That may help get to the root of the issue. However, at face value the name xState (where x is some letter) is not a reserved word in Groovy or Grails.

Comment: What problem are you having and what version of Grails are you using?

Comment: the error i am getting is from tomcat:

type Status report
message /mStage/index
description The requested resource is not available.

i named the domain class MStage, the controller MStageController and the views are in mStage.

Comment: the answers below from @jeff-scott-brown were a) polite b) accurate c) speedy. many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is xStage (for any x) reserved in grails?

No.

See the project at https://github.com/jeffbrown/stages which contains a domain class named TStage.  The controller unit test passes and interacting with the app for basic crud operations appears to work.

I can't think of anything special about *Stage.  You haven't said what problem you are having.  One thing that might be going wrong is a capitalization issue.  There were times when we had problems related to artifact names that began with multiple capital letters but I am not aware of any of those that are currently outstanding.

Comment: thank you for the quick response.

i notice that you put the views in TStage. i have used tStage.

Comment: it is because the url should be /TStage and not (what i expected) /tStage. i do not understand as this appears to break convention, but if it works...

Comment: I don't think it breaks convention.  I think it adheres to convention.  Specifically, it adheres to the JavaBean specifaction which describes how to decapitalize names that being with multiple upper case letters.  If you look at section 8.8 of http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/7224-javabeans-1.01-fr-spec-oth-JSpec/beans.101.pdf you will see the following: "...we check if the first two characters of the name are both upper case and if so leave it alone.".  Run `java.beans.Introspector.decapitalize('TStage')` and you will see the result is `TStage`.

Comment: i could not find anything in the grails doumentation. i was not aware of that. older and wiser. thank you very much for your help